# How can I test floating-point equality using chai?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, chai

We're using [Chai's BDD API](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) to write unit tests.

How can we assert floating point equality?

For example, if I try to make this assertion to check for a 66⅔% return value:

```
expect(percentage).to.equal(2 / 3 * 100.0);
```

I get this failure:

```
AssertionError: expected 66.66666666666667 to equal 66.66666666666666
Expected :66.66666666666666
Actual   :66.66666666666667
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I was looking for this too, and apart from this question, I also found [this discussion](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/89) regarding a feature request that led to the addition of [`closeTo`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#closetoexpected-delta-msg). With that you can specify a value and a +/- delta, so basically it lets you specify the precision with which to check the result.

```
percentage.should.be.closeTo(6.666, 0.001);
```

or

```
// `closeTo` is an alias for the arguably better name `approximately`
percentage.should.be.approximately(6.666, 0.001);
```

or

```
expect(percentage).to.be.closeTo(6.666, 0.001)
```

It's not perfect of course, because this will approve any number from 6.665 to 6.667.

Comment: I think the right syntax should actually be `percentage.to.be.closeTo(6.666, 0.001)`. At least the `should` didn't work for me.

Comment: @BrunoSilvano Thanks for the feedback. It depends on the type of assertions you use (either `expect` or `should`). See [the docs](https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/) on the differences and how to initialize them.

Comment: Actually in the should documentation it's not closeTo, but approximately. So the version with should is percentage.should.be.approximately(6.666, 0.001) https://shouldjs.github.io/#assertion-approximately

Comment: @Fuzzzzel Thanks. It looks like it was renamed at some point. According to the chai documentation they are aliases, but in `shouldJs` no mention of `closeTo` is found. I've added that example to the answer.

Answer (score 13):

The `within` assertion can be used to check whether a floating-point number is close to its intended result:

```
expect(percentage).to.be.within(66.666, 66.667);
```